# Удаление элементов листбокса при клике на кнопку

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется ListBox, в котором в шаблоне, объединенные в StackPanel, находятся Label и две кнопки, одна из них невидима. Как сделать так, что бы при нажатии на одну кнопку на 10 секунд появлялась вторая, а при нажатии на нее удалялась та строчка ListBox'а, к которой принадлежит эта кнопка?

P.S. Не привожу код ListBox'а, ибо он тут не нужен. (Если я ошибаюсь, и он тут нужен, то приложу)

Comment: Wpf? WinForms? Почему не указано в тегах?

Comment: Ну а как вы пробовали-то?

Comment: @Сергей да, забыл, извините. Андрей, что бы пробовать нужно иметь идею, которую нужно пытаться воплотить в жизнь. У меня идей, как это возможно реализовать нет.

Comment: `Visibility = Visible; await Task.Delay(10); Visible = Collapsed;`

Comment: @АндрейNOP это, конечно хорошо, но не то. Такой код я сам напишу. Мне нужно что бы по нажатию кнопки изменялась кнопка, находящаяся в том же элементе ЛистБокса, тут встает вопрос как отследить, в каком элементе нажалась кнопка (его, номер, допустим) и потом в этом же элементе изменить свойства другой кнопки

Comment: Есть такая штука как `CommandParameter`. Ну и про `Binding` и команды почитайте. Вы хоть минимально погуглить бы потрудились, прежде чем вопрос заводить. Тут на вопросы отвечают, а не делают работу за вас.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это делается не на уровне View, а на уровне VM.

На уровне VM у вас есть класс `ItemVM`, и в нём что-то такое:

```
class ItemVM : NotifyPropertyChangedImpl
{
    RelayCommand deleteCommand
    public ICommand DeleteCommand => deleteCommand;
    public ICommand EnableDeleteCommand { get; }

    public ItemVM(Action<ItemVM> onDelete)
    {
        deleteCommand = new RelayCommand(() => onDelete(this)) { IsEnabled = false };
        EnableDeleteCommand = new RelayCommand(OnEnable);
    }

    async void OnEnable()
    {
        deleteCommand.IsEnabled = true;
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        deleteCommand.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Ну и главная VM:

```
class MainVM : NotifyPropertyChangedImpl
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemVM> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ItemVM>();

    void OnDelete(ItemVM itemVM) => Items.Remove(itemVM);

    public MainVM()
    {
        Items.Add(new ItemVM(OnDelete));
    }
}
```

На уровне View стилизуйте кнопку удаления так, чтобы она не показывалась, если `command.IsEnabled == false`.